# Open vSwitch seems to not working (no redirection ping)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine, openvswitch, pox

I am using Docker and need to make a network when a container (sender) can ping 2nd container (receiver) but using OVS in the middle (for POX purpose).

I created containers but PING not working eg. ping 192.168.0.10 (receiver's IP).
I can ping only OVS container from both (sender and receiver).

Do I need to extra configure endpoints containers (clean alpine)?

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  sender:
    container_name: sender
    build:
      context: sender
    privileged: true
    networks:
      A:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.16.10
    tty: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    entrypoint: ["./entrypoint.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./sender/send.py:/send.py


  receiver:
    container_name: receiver
    build:
      context: receiver
    privileged: true
    networks:
      C:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.0.10
    tty: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    entrypoint: [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
    volumes:
      - ./receiver/rece.py:/rece.py

  vswtich_2:
    container_name: s2
    build:
      context: vSwitch
    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ./vSwitch/entrypoints:/entrypoints
    networks:
       A:
         ipv4_address: 192.168.16.100
       C:
         ipv4_address: 192.168.0.100
    environment:
      - EP=/entrypoints/entrypoint_0.sh
      - ENTRYPOINT=/entrypoints/entrypoint_0.sh
      - ip_A=192.168.16.100
      - ip_B=192.168.0.100
      - pox_ip=172.30.0.50
    entrypoint: ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]


networks:
  A:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.16.0/20
          gateway: 192.168.16.1
  C:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/20
          gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

On OVS I am using command (eth0 and eth1 is automatically established):

```
ovs-vsctl add-br myswitch -- set bridge myswitch datapath_type=netdev


eth_A=$(ip -o -4 addr | awk '{print $2, $4}' | grep $ip_A | awk '{print $1}')
eth_B=$(ip -o -4 addr | awk '{print $2, $4}' | grep $ip_B | awk '{print $1}')

echo $ip_A
echo $ip_B

echo  $eth_A
echo  $eth_B

ovs-vsctl add-port myswitch $eth_A -- set Interface $eth_A ofport_request=1
ovs-vsctl add-port myswitch $eth_B -- set Interface $eth_B ofport_request=2


ovs-ofctl add-flow myswitch in_port=1,actions=output:2
ovs-ofctl add-flow myswitch in_port=2,actions=output:1

ovs-vsctl show
```

```
/ # ovs-vsctl show
08c57a08-59e7-4915-83b2-4fa8422fef2f
    Bridge myswitch
        datapath_type: netdev
        Port eth0
            Interface eth0
        Port eth1
            Interface eth1
        Port myswitch
            Interface myswitch
                type: internal
```

OVS:

```
/ # ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:C0:A8:10:64  
          inet addr:192.168.16.100  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:158066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:158050 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11064892 (10.5 MiB)  TX bytes:11063500 (10.5 MiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:C0:A8:00:64  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:158063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:158049 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11064626 (10.5 MiB)  TX bytes:11063430 (10.5 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

OVS docker file:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY entrypoints entrypoints
RUN  chmod +x ./entrypoints/*

# Install dependencies
RUN apk --update add openssh supervisor openvswitch nano sudo bridge-utils dhclient  git bash tcpdump iptables

# ////////////// Open vSwitch Section ////////////// #

# Create database and pid file directory
RUN /usr/bin/ovsdb-tool create /etc/openvswitch/conf.db
RUN mkdir -pv /var/run/openvswitch/


# Add supervisord configuration file
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
COPY dhclinet.conf /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

# When container starts, supervisord is executed
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/supervisord
```

Comment: I switched to GNS3 using those container and it started to work